# How to synchronize data with OneDrive on UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, onedrive

To make a UWP App with OneDrive to synchronize data, I need Microsft Graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To make a UWP App with OneDrive to synchronize data, I need Microsft Graph

we could use [`OneDrive Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/services/onedrive) to approach, for synchronize data, you could refer [upload file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/services/onedrive#creating-or-uploading-files---that-exceed-4mb) part.

[OneDrive Service Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit//tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/OneDrive%20Service) Page Source. You can see this in action in Windows Community [Toolkit Sample App](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NBLGGH4TLCQ).

Comment: To create the folder go with the button of connection